# Postmessage not working with dynamic Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

HI I am trying to create an iframe and post a message by method using following code.

```
function sendMessage(){
    var text = document.getElementById("message").value;
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(text,"http://localhost");
}
```

I have added message event on iframe so that i can capture the respective event.

```
iframe.addEventListener("load",function(){iframeLoaded()},false)
iframe.contentWindow.window.
    addEventListener("message", function(event){handleMessage(e);},false);

function iframeLoaded(){
    alert("Iframe loaded");
}
function handleMessage(event){
    alert(event.data+" Message received");
}
```

Handle message is not getting called .
http://jsfiddle.net/k2wuk6t3/

Answer (score 1):

The reason we use `postMessage` is because it doesn't require access to the document loaded into the frame. This is because we can't access that document directly (for security reasons).

You are attempting to add the event listener by *directly accessing* the document loaded into the frame, so you'll be blocked for the same security reasons.

The document you load into the frame has to be responsible for setting up its own listener for your messages.

---

Your live demo ([SO has supported live demos for over a year](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), there's no need to resort to third parties for them) has an additional problem. You are creating the iframe, binding the `message` event listener to the document that is loaded into it by default, then setting the `src` so the document is thrown away (with the event listener) and a new one is loaded.

That is why you don't see a security exception there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by 'waiting' for the iframe to load before attaching any listeners to it.